# programmatically generate ppt in iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, core-graphics, presentation

For generating PDF files we can use Core Graphics. Similarly is there any framework / class that can be used for generating .ppt (power point presentation) files via code ? Or is there any third party framework for this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no in-built Apple API, and I've never heard of a third-party framework for this.

Comment: Yes there will be no native api designed by apple for creating Power Point Presentations.

Comment: Ok if I create PDF from core graphics can I convert it to PPT format (via coding) ? My aim is to somehow get PPT via my iOS application.

Comment: If you know of some PDF-to-PPT converter, then yes.

Comment: Funny I have wrongly framed my question :) My question is 'How to convert PDF to PPT in iOS ?'. Again any framework design for this purpose ?

Answer (score 2):

Seems there are still no open source solutions for this for iOS platform. Aspose seems to have something and another commercial that pretty recently emerged - [libpptx.com](http://libpptx.com), at least it provides some generic functionality to craft pptx