# Generate a ppt file with byte array/NSData, in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, file, download, powerpoint

I have a NSData value, generated from a byte array response. Now I need to save this as a .ppt file in iPhone/iPad, I learned from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295228/programmatically-generate-ppt-in-ios/19295918#19295918) link that there is no way to directly do it.

I already tried saving it as a PDF first, but failed in that too, since I'm unable to reproduce the charts from the nsdata.

Now is there another way to get this done other than sending the file through mail associated to the device?

Please do give out only the ways by which I can carry this out in the background without the help of the user? Any help will be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it working, tried a lot but nothing worked and finally ran into some random code blocks, using which I got this wonderful piece of code,

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------generating input URL

NSString *urlAddress = @"url containing the pdf data";
NSURL *theRessourcesURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------defining file location details & writing a ppt file with a name "new.ppt"

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pathFloder = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"new.ppt"]];
                                                         NSString *defaultDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:pathFloder];
NSData *tmp = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:theRessourcesURL];
[tmp writeToFile:defaultDBPath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: This does not seem to work, You have converted pdf to data and again are writing data to new file, are you sure that creates a ppt file?